# ‘is_sorted’ is not a member of ‘std’

Tags: c++

Почему компилятор выдает ошибку "‘is_sorted’ is not a member of ‘std’", хотя я подключил библиотеку algorithm

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> a;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        a.push_back(i);
    if (std::is_sorted(a.begin(), a.end()))
        std::cout << "YESSSSSSSS" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "NOOOOOOOOO" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Эта функция появилась в стандарте C++11. Соответственно, ваш компилятор должен поддерживать этот стандарт. В GCC (полностью поддерживает C++11 с версии 4.8) это делается так:

```
g++ .\main.cpp -o program.exe -std=c++11
```